# Subset Conditions closest higher/lower observation

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, subset

```
AreaCode    Name    Rank
1001108 HA  - 2326
1001247 HA  - 2327
1003063 GC -    2328
1000957 DG -    2329
1001290 EA -    2330
1003305 GC -    2331
1003417 GC -    2332
1006442 WL -    2333
1005076 PK - 2334
1004581 NL -    2335
```

I am new to R and am having some issues. I have a data set where I want to subset the closest higher/lower ranked AreaCodes to GC in order to do a case-control study.

So I want AreaCode 1001247, 1000957, 1001290, 1006442 in a seperate data frame. How do I do this? I’m assuming through a loop, but have no experience with these. This data has ~6000 observations so doing it by hand becomes exhausting. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean with closest? Closest nrs in Ranks/AreaCode, location?

Comment: Hi, yes - I want the closest in rank, so for each GC Area Code I want the closest ranked (higher & lower) Non-GC Area Code.

Comment: Please share your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative would be something like this (assuming Name is a character variable):

```
df2 = df %>% 
  mutate(newcol = ifelse(!Name=="GC"&(lag(Name)=="GC"|lead(Name)=="GC"),1,0) ) %>% 
  filter(newcol==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`cumsum` and `rle` are useful here

```
brks <- cumsum(rle(df$Name)$lengths) 
# [1]  2  3  4  5  7  8  9 10

equalsGC <- which(rle(df$Name)$values=="GC")
# [1] 2 5

ans <- df$AreaCode[sort(brks[c(equalsGC+1, equalsGC-1)])]
# [1] 1001247 1003063 1001290 1003417
```

As a single block

```
brks <- cumsum(rle(df$Name)$lengths) 
equalsGC <- which(rle(df$Name)$values=="GC")
ans <- df$AreaCode[sort(brks[c(equalsGC+1, equalsGC-1)])]
```